# How to iterate on a schema's properties types

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node.js, and I wanted to know if there is a way to iterate over the fields of a structure and know their types.

For exemple:

```
schema {
    origin: String,
    originDate: Date,
    arrival: String,
    arrivalDate: Date,
    passagers: {
        adults: Number,
        children: Number
    }
}
```

For example:

I want to loop in the `scheema` and know what is the type of each field.

Expected response:

```
String
Date
String
Date
Object
```

and also know what that object has.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) The structure you've provded isn't valid JavaScript (nor TypeScript, if we try to guess at what you're doing). Please update the question with an accurate version of what you have, tagging any relevant technologies (TypeScript? Flow?), and saying precisely what you want to do.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` I'm not sure what is your use case but consider taking a look into swagger openApi schema validation https://github.com/kogosoftwarellc/open-api/tree/master/packages/openapi-schema-validator

Answer (score 0):

Answer here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic is to pass a object type to a Object.keys() function which will return the list with all the keys

```
const user = new User(); // create new object
const schemaKeys = Object.keys(user.toObject());
console.log("The keys are",schemaKeys)
```